# _trackEvent() from Google Analytics not working?

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google Analytics setup on my site, and it is definitely recording page views.  But I have added some code to call `pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, label, value)`, and it is not recording those hits or showing them in the reports.

BTW, yes, I have waited for over 24hrs to see if the hits are in the reports.

I have used the standard Google script include as well as the technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753514/how-to-dynamically-load-google-analytics-javascript).  Neither one seems to help the `_trackEvent()` problem.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to track down what's going wrong?  I'd be happy to post code examples if you let me know what parts are important.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some real world code snippet how you applied it? According to your description, everything is alright.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem was the values that I was putting in the final argument, the "value" parameter.

```
pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, label, value)
```

I was passing non-integer strings to the "value" parameter:

```
pageTracker._trackEvent("UserAction", "ShowHelp", "Page", "http://mysite/UrlGoesHere");
```

but the docs say it needs to be an integer value.

```
pageTracker._trackEvent("UserAction", "ShowHelp", "http://mysite/UrlGoesHere",  1);
```

I posed [the question](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?fid=6151ced89aaddd6b00046f2a2e55db2b&hl=en) on Google Help Forums here.

And here is a link to the [Event Tracking docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

Thanks for the help Török

Comment: you saved my day. i was in stuck with it by sending a float as the value and it was not working :(. thanks a lot.

Comment: Note: the google analytics debugger chrome plugin (developed by Google) is clever enough to report this problem : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: Also general debugging guidelines can be useful https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting

Comment: This only works if you have the async Google Analytics tracking code installed on the same page... https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Comment: Good to note that **integer** seems to be wanted, even though [some documentation ](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) says **number**.

Answer (score 7):

Similarly, label can not be an integer or the _trackEvent function fails silently.

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('VLP', 'click-out', 12345);
```

Fixed as

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('VLP', 'click-out', '12345');
```

Answer (score 4):

**Updated Answer**

This question is still getting a lot of pageviews. I feel like the current visitors are facing a new problem that the other answers don't address.

**New Analytics Means New APIs**

If you are using the "Universal Analytics" snippet which is Google's new system they are trying to transition everyone over to. Some of the APIs have changed including event tracking.

**Make sure you are using this:**

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, value);
```

**Instead of this:**

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, value]);
```

**For event tracking.**

Here is a thorough blog post on the subject http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/tracking-events-in-googles-new-universal-analytics/

And here is the new documentation from Google https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> it is not recording those hits or
>   showing them in the reports.

Events have no effect on page views and do not appear on regular reports. Events have a seperate interface at [Content / Events](https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/events). If you'd like to track the things you specified as events like regular hits, better use the `trackPageview` method instead.

Comment: You are correct, events are not regular page hits.  Unfortunately (for me), I did know that, but the events are still not showing up in  Content/Events.

Comment: @slolife: have you tried to manually change the URL? For instance, click on ‘Content/Site Search’ and replace ‘site_search’ with ‘events’?