# Google Analytics trackEvent code isn't working

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

GA trackEvent code isn't working.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Clicked', 'Button', 'Home']);"
```

The code above should be working but for some reason it's not. I'm looking at "Real Time" view in Google Analytics, on the "Events" tab and nothing shows up when I click.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fourth parameter (value) should be an integer, not a string:

> _trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) category (required) The name you supply for the
>   group of objects you want to track.
>
> action (required) A string that is uniquely paired with each category,
>   and commonly used to define the type of user interaction for the web
>   object.
>
> label (optional) An optional string to provide additional dimensions
>   to the event data.
>
> **value (optional) An integer** that you can use to provide numerical data
>   about the user event.
>
> non-interaction (optional) A boolean that when set to true, indicates
>   that the event hit will not be used in bounce-rate calculation.

from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: Back in those days someone had the same problem with the synchronous tracking code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145639/trackevent-from-google-analytics-not-working?rq=1. I frankly don't know if this should count as a duplicate.