# How to load Google Analytics after page load

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dynamically load Google Analytics JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753514/how-do-i-dynamically-load-google-analytics-javascript)

Hi Google Analytics call is slowing down my web page load. Is there a way to initiate call to Google Analytics only after the complete web page has been rendered?

Comment: Previously asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753514/how-do-i-dynamically-load-google-analytics-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Generally the new analytics js code has a setting to load asynchronously(after the page has loaded that is). Something like

```
ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
```

I also think you can get the asynchronous code from the "tracking code" of the analytics panel if you choose to display the advanced options but i'm not sure about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about [Asynchronous Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html)? It shouldn't affect page load…

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous GA snippet, extracted from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://h5bp.com):

```
var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID 
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
```